# FirebaseObjectObservable mapping to property

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

What I am trying to achieve is a sort of join by using RxJs.

```
const placeId = this.auth.getPlaceId();
return this.database.list(`/${TransactionsService.SECONDARY_NODE}/${placeId}`, {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'date',
                startAt: start,
                endAt: end
            }
        }).map(items => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.length = items.length;
            return items.reverse();
        });
```

What I want is to map the 'user_id' property of a transaction to an actual user. This user can be retrieved using this endpoint.

```
this.database.list(`users/${user-id})
```

But when i try to use flatMap to map the property to the observable, i dont get the object when i subscribe to it. It just sets the user_id to the firebaseobjectobservable object.

How can this be achieved using RxJs?